# Ошибка array to string

Tags: php, mysql

Достаю следующим образом из БД значение:

```
$info=DB::select('select created_at from zayavkas where id = ?',[$city_name[5]]);
```

По идее сейчас в `$info` находится одна переменная, но в итоге когда пытаюсь вывести через echo, получаю ошибку, что это массив.

В итоге работает, если сделать вот так:

```
foreach($info as $info1){ echo $info1->created_at; }
```

И разумеется там всего 1но число.

Comment: По какой такой "идее"? Откуда эта идея взялась?

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтоб получить объект не "завернутый" в массив можно сделать так:

`$info=DB::select('select created_at from zayavkas where id = ?',[$city_name[5]])[0]`.

Если же в получаемом массиве ключ строковый, то можно воспользоваться функцией `array_shift()`, которая извлечет первый элемент массива:

`$zayavka = array_shift($info);`